# JXTable - how to update highlighters on sorting the table

Tags: java, swing, swingx, jxtable, tablerowsorter

I have a JXTable with custom table model. I added 2 ColorHighlighter's with custom HighlightPredicate's.

Problem is when i click on the column header, the table sorts the rows, BUT the highlighter's remain as for the old view.

How can I update the state of the highlight after sorting a table?

Comment: have convert view index to model `model int modelRow = convertRowIndexToModel(row)`, maybe works, maybe not depends of SwingX version,

Comment: there are a few another issues, better could be post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) , short, runnable, compilable, for potentials answerers and future readers too

Comment: Thank you, I will add a simple example later today.

Comment: show the predicate you are using to control the highlighter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @kleopatra mentioned, i looked at my predicate:

```
    HighlightPredicate spakowany = new HighlightPredicate() {
        @Override
        public boolean isHighlighted(Component renderer, ComponentAdapter adapter) {
            TableModel tableModel = table.getModel();
            if (tableModel instanceof StanTableModel) {
                StanTableModel stanTableModel = (StanTableModel) tableModel;
                // int rowIndex = adapter.row;  <-  this was the issue 
                int rowIndex = adapter.convertRowIndexToModel(adapter.row);
                StanTableRow myCustomRow = stanTableModel.getRow(rowIndex);
                if ((myCustomRow.isSpakowany()) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
```

and used @mKorbel idea:

was:

```
    int rowIndex = adapter.row;
```

is now:

```
    int rowIndex = adapter.convertRowIndexToModel(adapter.row);
```

And it works now.

**StanTableModel** is my custom table model. It has **getRow()** function and returns a **StanTableRow** object which in turn has **isSpakowany()** function.

Comment: glad you found the problem :-) Consider to change the code snippet with the correctly working line (that is the one with the converted rowIndex), otherwise it's a tad confusing.

Comment: @kleopatra is there another way, meaning `HighlightPredicate` and with `getTableModel`, couldn't be fragile ???